# handle addEventListener in if condition based on localStorage boolean value

Tags: javascript, local-storage, addeventlistener

I'm trying to switch the theme based on OS level light/dark mode. Users may change the system settings while using the website. So, I need to update in real-time instead of page refresh. So, I'm using `addEventListener`to get system current changes. `addEventListener` works fine. But, It should work if the System Settings option is set to true.

I have stored System Settings as a boolean option in localStorage. **If it is true then the only addEventListener should work. If it is false it should not work.** But, my problem is addEventListener work in both cases. I mean it works if System Settings is neither true nor false. How do I handle addEventListener should work based on localStorage value (if System Settings sets true)?

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81mgdsp9/9/)**

**JS**

```
function defaultFunction() {
    localStorage.setItem('option', 'default');
  localStorage.setItem('systemOption', false);
}
defaultFunction();

function myFunction() {
  let getOption = localStorage.getItem('option');
  let themeDiv = document.getElementById('theme');
  
  if(localStorage.getItem('systemOption') == 'true') {
    let osTheme = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
    osTheme.addEventListener('change', event => {
      if(event.matches) {
        themeDiv.classList.add("dark");
        themeDiv.classList.remove("default");
      } else {
        themeDiv.classList.add("default");
        themeDiv.classList.remove("dark");
      }
    })
  } else {
    if(getOption == 'dark') {
      themeDiv.classList.add("dark");
      themeDiv.classList.remove("default");
    } else if(getOption == 'default') {
      themeDiv.classList.add("default");
      themeDiv.classList.remove("dark");
    }
  }
}
myFunction();

function setDark() {
    localStorage.setItem('option', 'dark');
  myFunction();
}

function setLight() {
    localStorage.setItem('option', 'default');
  myFunction();
}

function checkBox() {
    let cBox = document.getElementById('system');
  let sun = document.getElementById('sun');
  let moon = document.getElementById('moon');
  
  if(cBox.checked) {
    localStorage.setItem('systemOption', true);
    sun.classList.add('addOpacity');
    moon.classList.add('addOpacity');
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('systemOption', false);
    sun.classList.remove('addOpacity');
    moon.classList.remove('addOpacity');
  }
  myFunction();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying this code on JsFiddle?

Comment: Have you tested if the event listener is working when you change the system settings?

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee Tried in both local file and JsFiddle. Yes, I have tested. When I change the system settings event listener works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is you are adding an event listener but you never removed it thus it's always listening for that event.

Try adding/removing event listener conditionally like below

```
function changeListener(event) {
  if(event.matches) {
    themeDiv.classList.add("dark");
    themeDiv.classList.remove("default");
  } else {
    themeDiv.classList.add("default");
    themeDiv.classList.remove("dark");
  }
}


let osTheme = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
if(localStorage.getItem('systemOption') === 'true') {
    osTheme.addEventListener('change', changeListener);
} else {
    osTheme.removeEventListener('change', changeListener);
}
```

### OR

Listen for event always and apply theme conditionally by checking `localStorage`

```
const osTheme = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
osTheme.addEventListener('change', event => {
    if(localStorage.getItem('systemOption') === 'true') {
        if(event.matches) {
            themeDiv.classList.add("dark");
            themeDiv.classList.remove("default");
        } else {
            themeDiv.classList.add("default");
            themeDiv.classList.remove("dark");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

now it works.

```
<div id="theme">
  Testing based on User OS level light/dark theme
</div>
<div class="option">
  <span id="sun" class="lightCls" onclick="setLight();">Light</span>
  <span id="moon" class="darkCls" onclick="setDark();">Dark</span>
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox" id="system" onclick="checkBox();" />
    <label for="system">System Setttings</label>
  </span>
</div>

<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#theme {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.default {
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
}
.dark {
  background: #101010;
  color: #fff;
}
.option {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 3px;
}
.lightCls, .darkCls {
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.lightCls {
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
}
.darkCls {
  background: #101010;
  color: #fff;
}
.addOpacity {
  opacity: 0.2;
  pointer-events: none;
}
</style>

<script>
function defaultFunction() {
    localStorage.setItem('option', 'default');
  localStorage.setItem('systemOption', false);
}
defaultFunction();

function myFunction() {
  let getOption = localStorage.getItem('option');
  let themeDiv = document.getElementById('theme');
  
  if(localStorage.getItem('systemOption') == 'true') {
    let osTheme = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
    osTheme.addEventListener('change', event => {
      if(event.matches) {
        themeDiv.classList.add("dark");
        themeDiv.classList.remove("default");
      } else {
        themeDiv.classList.add("default");
        themeDiv.classList.remove("dark");
      }
    })
  } else {
    if(getOption == 'dark') {
      themeDiv.classList.add("dark");
      themeDiv.classList.remove("default");
    } else if(getOption == 'default') {
      themeDiv.classList.add("default");
      themeDiv.classList.remove("dark");
    }
  }
}
myFunction();

function setDark() {
    localStorage.setItem('option', 'dark');
  myFunction();
}

function setLight() {
    localStorage.setItem('option', 'default');
  myFunction();
}

function checkBox() {
    let cBox = document.getElementById('system');
  let sun = document.getElementById('sun');
  let moon = document.getElementById('moon');
  
  if(cBox.checked) {
    localStorage.setItem('systemOption', true);
    sun.classList.add('addOpacity');
    moon.classList.add('addOpacity');
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('systemOption', false);
    sun.classList.remove('addOpacity');
    moon.classList.remove('addOpacity');
  }
  myFunction();
}

</script>
```